# How to change the password of Db2 running on Docker?

Tags: docker, db2

I've been using Db2 on Docker with no issues. Today, it says that the password expired.

> [jcc][t4][2012][11248][4.27.25] Connection authorization failure
> occurred.  Reason: Password expired. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2w/docs/content/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/changing_bluadmin_password.html) post I need to run  `docker exec -it Db2wh setpass new_password`  where Db2wh is the container name, but I get

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting
> container process caused: exec: "setpass": executable file not found
> in $PATH: unknown

How to fix this? I also tried to log in the container's console and run `setpass new_password` but the command was not found. How to change this password?

Comment: Can you shell into the container as root and run the `passwd` command for the userid whose password is expired, for example `passwd bluadmin` ?  While there, can you run the `find` command to locate `setpass` ? (cannot tell from your question exactly which image of Db2 is running in the container).

Comment: @mao running with root `find -name setpass` in the container command line doesn't return anything

Comment: use `find / -name "setpass".`  Did you follow the advice to use the `passwd ` command (as root) for the userid whose password is expired?  From which image is your container started?  If you give no facts, how do you expect to get help?

Comment: I got the image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) Db2 version 11.5.5. The find that you sent me didn't return anything either and I run it with root

Comment: so you are not running the Db2-warehouse version, but the Db2 community edition?

Comment: Apparently yes, how to change the password (and if possible also disable password expiration)?

Comment: Thanks. Running `passwd db2inst1` in the shell of the Db2 community edition worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to shell into the container as root, and to run the command `passwd db2inst1`  (or whatever the name of the instance owner, default is `db2inst1`).

The question gave a doc link to a command that is valid for the Db2-warehouse edition. However the actual image used was the Db2 community edition , which is the reason the `setpass` command was not valid.

To change password expiry interval or disable expiry, once again shell into the container as root and run whatever command is relevant for the distro used by the image. For example user the `chage` command with appropriate options.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked like this:

```
docker exec -u root -it db2 passwd db2admin
```

where "db2" is your container name and db2admin is a user name